# When does a cylinder sweeping through space leave a pair of ruled surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let's define a cylinder segment as the cartesian product of a unit disk with an interval (without loss of generality make that $[-1,1]$), or any rotation+translation of this initial shape.
This gives you two disks at each end of the cylinder segment each with a center, call them $P_1$ and $P_2$. Now suppose you have two smooth parametric curves $f$, $g$ in 3-dimensional space so that $P_1$ is positioned at $f(t)$ and $P_2$ is positioned at $g(t)$ as $t$ moves from an initial value $a$ to a final value $b$. Under favourable circumstances the cylinder segment will sweep a volume with sides that are ruled surfaces. Has anybody studied this?

The problem arises in computer assisted manufacturing where the cylinder segment is used to remove matter from a solid block as it moves through it. Of course we are ignoring the half-cylindrical ends of the swept volume, as well as the part swept out by the two ends of the cylinder segment.